# Is it possible to mute index of data frame from print function?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to mute the index from printing in my dataframe. How would I do this using pandas?

```
Current output:

0        Prob(name) = 100.0%
1        Prob(name) = 0.0%

Expected output:
Prob(name) = 100.0%
Prob(name) = 0.0%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```